# De ViewBag a JSON

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc

Estoy pasando un ViewBag de controlador a la vista y quisiera pasarlo a un array numérico en JavaScript.

El contenido del ViewBag:

> "12,13,17,18,19,8,9,14"

Mi último intento ha sido este:

```
var horas = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.HorasBloquear));
var array = JSON.parse(horas);
```

al realizar el parse me salta el error:

> VM253:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token , in JSON at position 2

¿A alguien se le ocurre como pasar el ViewBag a un array numérico ?

Answer (score 1):

Ya conseguí obtener el array facilmente.

```
var horas = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.HorasBloquear));
var arrayBloqueo = horas.split(',');
```

Answer (score 0):

No puedo probarlo pero creo que esto te funcionará :

```
var jss = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer(); 
var horasBloquear= jss.Serialize(ViewBag.HorasBloquear);

var array =  JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(horasBloquear)');
```

Comment: no me deja usar new "System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();"